# Dropbox file picker Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to create some file pickers in Android. Is it possible to make picker just for Dropbox files? For example now I added filter to select only .png files and it opens 2 options Dropbox and Gallery and if I select Dropbox I get the picker (look at the attachment). In case the user is not logged in I get login page for Dropbox. What I want to do is to make my own chooser (with options like Dropbox, Box, Camera etc. this can be a DialogFragment foe example) and when the user selects Dropbox I want to start the picker that I attached. Also I am not sure is it possible to check if Dropbox is installed on the phone and/or if user is logged in already (I know this is possible on iOS). [image]

Comment: hey i want to do same thing can u tell me how can i do this ?
i use dropbox chooser library but it give me always dropbox download option. I want to do like you post the photo. Help me if you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Dropbox in your App, This is might help you https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/42/the-chooser-now-for-ios-and-android

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.